# Dipstick reading little to no oil

Tags: oil, oil-level

I took my car to Midas to get a oil leak inspected and a diagnosis and was told I had several leaks so they said that the main leak was coming from the main valve cover so they change that out. I took the vehicle home check the oil level said it had no oil on it so I called Midas and they put oil on it. He said yes, the car continue to leak the same as it did before no different so I took it to a mechanic shop where they repaired the issue that was causing the main leak of the engine oil when I got home I checked the oil level and the dipstick said it had no oil in it again I called mechanic shop. The mechanic shop said they did put the full amount of oil that is recommended for my vehicle, the car was not leaking any oil at all they had stopped so I went ahead and put 3 quarts of oil inside, the engine started the car and smoke came out of the muffler and smoking really bad from the exhaust and my brakes became very hard to push and my gas became very easy to push but I’m still not leaking really any oil. I checked the dipstick on the oil, and it says that I am to the one line , I need to add more. I called the mechanic shop and told them about the issue and they told me that I flooded the engine with oil at least that’s what they believe their knowledge

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I see you are having issues, but what exactly is your question? I'm not seeing it here.